# Accessing DI elements like IConfiguration from within nested class in a Core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application

I have browsed many tutorials and watch several videos regarding using DI in .NET Core console applications. However, they all seem to fall a little short of what I'm looking for. In a large console app we might have multiple classes being called/referenced and each of these classes may have a need to access the logger or the config settings. All of the tutorials and explanations I have come across have only shown one level deep and passing the logging and configuration DI instances to the first level.

What if Class 1 calls Class 2, which then calls class 3. Say class 3 needs to get a configuration value or class 2 needs to write some informational or debug data to the log. How does one access ILogger and IConfiguration using DI in classes 2 and 3?

I have created a very simple example here based on the video tutorial of Tim Corey, "[.NET Core Console App with Dependency Injection, Logging, and Settings](https://youtu.be/GAOCe-2nXqc?si=Ew3CYdaKP8HCXMIV)", where he sets up config and serilog for a console app. but again, he only goes as deep as the initial worker class.

The app consists of 3 main classes, Program.cs (used to set up configurations), Runner.cs (the worker service class), and SubClass.cs (the sub class called from Runner.cs). My code works for logging and retrieving settings in the worker service class (Runner.cs), but when I try to access the logger or the config settings from the SubClass, I run into issues.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

namespace DiConsoleExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            BuildConfig(builder);

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger.Information("Application Starting");

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<IRunner, Runner>();
                })
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();

            var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Runner>(host.Services);
            svc.Run();
        }

        static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

    }
}
```

**Runner.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DiConsoleExample
{
    public interface IRunner
    {
        void Run();
    }

    public class Runner : IRunner
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Runner> _log;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Runner(ILogger<Runner> log, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _log = log;
            _config = config;
        }


        public void Run()
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Value for 'MyRunnerSetting': {settingValue}", _config.GetValue<string>("MyRunnerSetting"));

            var sub = new SubClass();
            sub.GetMySetting();
        }
    }
}
```

**SubClass.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DiConsoleExample
{
    public class SubClass
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Runner> _log;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public SubClass(ILogger<Runner> log, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _log = log;
            _config = config;
        }

        public void GetMySetting()
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Value for 'MySubClassSetting': {settingValue}", _config.GetValue<string>("MySubClassSetting"));
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "MyRunnerSetting": "Runner123",
  "MySubClassSetting":  "SubClass234"
}
```

The error I'm getting is that when I create a new SubClass() it can't use the DI injected Log and Config services: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'log' of 'SubClass.SubClass(ILogger<Runner>, IConfiguration)`

Again, this works fine if the call to SubClass is not made in Runner.cs, but I need to know how to access the Logger and Configurations through DI. I know I can put the build/configure statements for each in each class, but that seems to defeat the purpose of DI and duplicates code.

Oh, and I am using .NET 8 in VS 2022.

---

EDIT. I should not have used "SubClass" in my explanation as it does not inherit from anything. I should have used "NestedClass" (my bad)

My question since my Runner.cs might new up multiple nested classes in a large app, how do I get the ILogger and IConfiguration into those nested classes?

In the .net framework, I could put log4net in any nested class to start logging or call ConfigurationManager in any class to get a setting. In Core ASP.NET I can use a constructor with ILogger and IConfiguration in every controller, but I can't figure out how to get to or reference  ILogger and IConfiguration in any nested classes beyond the Runner.cs service.

Comment: That's a compilation error that has nothing to do with DI. The class `Subclass` isn't a subclass of any other class and its constructor requires 2 parameters.  `var sub = new SubClass();` provides neither, resulting in a compilation error. You'll have to use `new SubClass(_log,_config)`. `SubClass` is actually a *nested* class. That doesn't mean it derives from the outer class or that it inherits its members.

Comment: `this works fine if the call to SubClass is not made in Runner.cs` no way, the same compilation error will be generated. `SubClass(ILogger<Runner> log, IConfiguration config)` requires two parameters. If you don't provide them you'll get a compilation error

Comment: Instead of newing `SubClass` by hand in the `Runner.Run` method, try supplying `Subclass` as constructor argument to the `Runner` constructor and a mapping to it inside the `ConfigureServices` method: e.g. `services.AddTransient<SubClass>()`.

Comment: You are right @PanagiotisKanavos, it's not a subclass, it's nested, sorry wrong terminaology, but to your second statement, if I comment out "var sub = new SubClass();
 sub.GetMySetting();" then the app runs fine and the proper output for runner is made. With the subclass instantiations, I get the error, yes because it doesn't have the ILogger and IConfiguration, but that is my main question, how do I set it up so I use the constructor with ILogger and IConfiguration using DI or do I have to pass the _log and _config objects to every nested class inside Runner.cs?

Comment: @Steven, I understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure what this would accomplish. In .net framework with a single line I could get log4net accessible in any nested class and config just by using the ConfigurationManager in ANY nested class. If I have 3 nested classes called from Runner doing different functions, how do I inject the Logger and Configuration into those multiple nested classes or classes inside those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away all the things you know about .NET Framework regarding logging and configuration, because they're irrelevant in the .NET (Core) world. You never manually `new` classes up, the DI framework [provides them for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). And you don't bind directly to `IConfiguration`, you use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options). So your classes would look something like this:

```
public record SubClassOptions(
    string MySubClassSetting);

public class Runner
{
    private ILogger<Runner> _logger;
    private ISubClass _subClass;

    public Runner(ILogger<Runner> logger, ISubClass subClass)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _subClass = subClass;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _subClass.GetMySetting();
    }
}

public interface ISubClass
{
    void GetMySetting();
}

public class SubClass : ISubClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<Runner> _logger;
    private readonly SubClassOptions _options;

    public SubClass(ILogger<Runner> log, SubClassOptions config)
    {
        _log = log;
        _config = config;
    }

    public void GetMySetting()
    {
        _log.LogInformation(
            "Value for 'MySubClassSetting': {SettingValue}",
            _config.MySubClassSetting);
    }
}
```

and your service registrations:

```
services.AddSingleton<SubClassOptions>(
    configuration.GetRequiredSection("SubClassSection").Get<SubClassOptions>());
services.AddScoped<ISubClass, SubClass>();
services.AddScoped<Runner>();
```

Comment: So I tweaked my sample and this works, however, it seems like a HUGE amount of overhead, especially when we are talking about an app that may have many nested classes inside many nested classes. All just so that each class can write to a log or get a config setting. I used to write 'private static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(LogType.CMS.ToString());' in any class and I could log in that class, but now to log I have to add all classes to the service collection? My app does not NEED Di, but I can't see a way to get log and config without it in core. All examples I found show using DI.

Comment: Your app does need DI, because nothing in .NET (Core) works without DI. Static instances are an antipattern because they prevent testing, DI is the solution to that. DI is the standard in modern software development and you are not going to get away from it, so I strongly suggest you consult some tutorials and videos on its benefits.

Comment: Also I would advise you adjust your mentality regarding migrating your .NET Framework app to .NET. It may still be C#, but the fundamental concepts have changed drastically, and massaging your code to fit those new concepts is unlikely to be a trivial affair. This is always the case when working with legacy code (yes, .NET Framework code is very much legacy at this point).